# Find all ContextMenuStrips defined on a Windows Form (not necessarily attached at runtime)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my winforms project, some of the forms have a set of ContextMenuStrips defined on them (through the visual studio designer).

Some of these contextmenustrips have been attached to controls, but others have not.

Now my problem is this: I need to go through all of the ContextMenuStrips at runtime, whether they are attached or not.

I've got some code that will recursively go through all controls and check the ContextMenuStrip property and this works fine.... However I can not get to the ContextMenuStrips that haven't been assigned to a control yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ContextMenuStrip components that you drop on a form with the designer are added to the "components" collection.  You can find them back by iterating it:

```
    For Each co As System.ComponentModel.Component In Me.components.Components
        If TypeOf co Is ContextMenuStrip Then
            Dim cms = DirectCast(co, ContextMenuStrip)
            '' do something
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... But now my next problem is trying to access the components that are defined on a form, from another class. Is there an easy way to do this without modifying the original form? Otherwise I have a considerable amount of code to change

Comment: That's a different question, asked many times before.  Find the answers back with the Search box.